# i'm trying to create a prompt for this input type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, command-prompt, prompt

i want to create a prompt command like this:

```
javascript:(function(){  javascript:prompt("Press CMD+C (Mac) or CTRL+C (Win)", $(".g-recaptcha").attr("data-sitekey"));})();
```

I want similar for this input

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="5DjeyPP5AaEiAXWn">
```

I want a prompt that shows input value..
Is it possible? thanks

Comment: To get hidden elements value use `$('[name="form_key"]').val()`

Comment: this? `javascript:prompt('Form Key',document.getElementsByName('form_key').value);`